# Why MPMoviePlayerController alway show empty black screen?

Tags: video, ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller

Code for init video player:

```
NSURL * url  =[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov"];
_player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: url ];
[_player.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:_player.view];
_player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
      //    [_player prepareToPlay];
[_player play];
```

But it always show black screen when I test in ipad  iOS 7, how I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your project. add button and attach the playMovie method to it.
and create your MPMoviPlayer object here

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
@interface ViewController ()
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
}

- (IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender {
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov"];

    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];
    moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
    CGRect frame;
    if(self.interfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
        frame = CGRectMake(20, 69, 280, 170);
    }
    else if(self.interfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || self.interfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        frame = CGRectMake(20, 61, 210, 170);
    }
    [moviePlayer.view setFrame:frame];  // player's frame must match parent's
    [self.view addSubview: moviePlayer.view];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:moviePlayer.view];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                         name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                       object:moviePlayer];

    [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {

    moviePlayer = [notification object];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];

    if ([moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
    {
        [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

may this code help you.

Comment: if i copy your code into new project it run well, but i copy it to my project it  show black screen.

Answer (score 0):

Just add 
**swift**

```
moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
```

in **oc**

```
[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
```